# C++ tag to force reserved parameter to be a nullptr

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function `func(int a, char b, void *ptr)`. The third parameter is reserved for internal use and it should be a `nullptr` for the current release. Is there a way to force this in the function prototype rather than the definition (checking and returning EINVAL)? By "better way" I mean some sort of new C++11 features that enable this.

Comment: Umm...what about a default argument?

Comment: What about a `static_assert()`, I assume you want a compiler error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could change the type of the third parameter from `void*` to `nullptr_t` (`#include <cstddef>`).

Comment: Yes I think this should do the job! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It reads like you're looking for [default parameter values](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/77-default-parameters/). Make your prototype `func (int a, char b, void *ptr = nullptr)` and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: That still allows calling with a non-NULL pointer though (I believe he wants to prevent that).